# Convert a key value list to a dataframe

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have a key / value list in R called country :

```
print(country)
$CAM
[1] 5

$TJK
[1] 1

$SEN
[1] 7
```

the key is the name of a country and the value an occurence of this one.

And i would like to convert this list as a dataframe like ths  :

```
  country  occurence
0 CAM      5
0 TJK      1
0 SEN      7
```

thanks and regards

Comment: @Sotos, in the linked question the input is not a named list

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can unlist and stack the input-list:

```
stack(unlist(country))
#  values ind
#1      5 CAM
#2      1 TJK
#3      7 SEN
```

Comment: you don't need `unlist`, just `stack(country)` works as well